# Como resolver o erro Flutter CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED ao executar uma requisição GET?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou estou solicitando uma requisiçao GET em Dart. Quando eu executo o app. Dá-me o seguinte erro:-

`Ocorreu uma exceção. HandshakeException (HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: Hostname mismatch(handshake.cc:393)))`

*Aqui está o meu código da função:*

```
Future<void> fetchFruits() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://www.fruityvice.com/api/fruit/all'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        fruits = jsonDecode(response.body);
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to fetch fruits');
    }
  }
```

*A API que estou utilizando: https://fruityvice.com/doc/index.html#api-GET-getAll*

Comment: Em `Uri.parse('https://www.fruityvice.com/api/fruit/all')` você deve utilizar da seguinte forma `Uri.parse('https://fruityvice.com/api/fruit/all')` sem o `www.` em sua url.

Comment: funcionou obriado.